# Fetching current user in Django FormView

Tags: django, django-forms

Im building a listings site and each user is linked to a company. Before the user can post a new listing it must have bought credits. If there are no credits the FormView should show a template with a notification of 0 credits, however if credits > 0 then the actual form should appear.

Im struggling in trying to fetch the current user in the `FormView` class itself. I know that it can be done via the `form_valid` method `user = self.request.user`, but that would mean that the user must first fill the whole form and submit it after checking if he has enough credits. Im trying to figure out how to perform the check before the form has been filled and submitted. I couldnt find resources how can I do something like this:

```
class CreateAd(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    if currents_user.ad_credits > 0:
        template_name = 'ads/ad_form.html'
        form_class = AdForm
        success_url = '/'
    else:
        template_name = 'ads/not_enough_credits.html'
        form_class = AdForm
        success_url = '/'
```

Comment: I think that you can use an ajax background call to check if this user has some credits. If yes display the form, if not hide the form and display **no credits available message**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that adding the current user object via `get_context_data(`) and then rendering the template based on `{% if current_user.ad_credits > 0 %}` was the easiest solution for me. If credits are low the template will only show a notification that the user should top up.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['current_user'] = self.request.user
    return context
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get_form_kwargs`:

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
    user = self.request.user
    kwargs['initial'] = ... # here update the form kwargs based on user
    return kwargs
```

Comment: But how to get the kwarg in the proposed if statement of the FormView?

Answer (score 0):

You can override 'get' function like this.

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if currents_user.ad_credits > 0:
        super(CreateAd, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
    else:
        raise HttpResponseBadRequest # Or what kind of error that you like
```